# Eclipse PDT and custom PHPDoc annotations

Tags: php, eclipse, phpunit, phpdoc, eclipse-pdt

Is there any way to add custom phpdoc annotation for Eclipse PDT?
For example, I want to see `@depends` (for PHPUnit) in autocomplete list for comments, but now I can see there only standard annotations (for example, `@deprecated`) .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not exactly following what it is you're looking for here in Eclipse PDT... please clarify, maybe with a more explained example.

Comment: When I make PHPDoc comment for the elemnt, I want to see in autocomplete not only standard tags (@author, @package, @deprecated, @returns, etc.) but also my custom annotations (e.g, @depends). How I can add such annotations?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assumed there would be a configuration file somewhere, but looking through the various folders in my Zend Studio installation didnt give me the results I was hoping for. Searching Eclipse.org for Content Assist yielded

- http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/editors_contentassist.htm

So I guess the "real" way to add a new Content Assist Context would be to extend Eclipse.

**Alternative: Using Templates**

The other way to get the annotations would be to add them via Templates. Follow these steps:

- Go to Window > Preferences > PHP > Editor > Templates.
- Click New, fill in the dialogue and confirm everything to get back to your editor

[image]

The template is now setup to appear when in the context of a PHP Comment. Go to a UnitTest DocBlock and type `@`. If Content Assist does not open automatically, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. There should be an option to select `@depends` now.

[image]

Confirm as you would confirm any other suggestion. This should write `@depends` and put your cursor right next to it (so you can insert the name of the test).

Comment: this worked for me very well. I have one question. Is there a way I could enumerate the possible values for a variable in the template itself.
lets say I have a template 
`@Column(name="${name}", type="${type}")`
Here the possible values for "type" are limited. So I am looking for a way to define it like a list of possible values say ["integer","string"]...

Comment: @Broncha tbh, I dont know. Check the help file linked in my answer. If it's possible it should be in there.