# Custom tags in phpdoc

Tags: php, eclipse, phpdoc

As you know you can use in PHP comments some tags like `@return` or `@throws` which also appear in the tooltip while hovering over a function name like this:

```
    Returns:
        << Return value >>
    Throws:
        << List of exceptions >>
```

I want to create my own tags which appear as paragraph in the tooltip. I already added my custom tag as template like described here [Eclipse PDT and custom PHPDoc annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920593/eclipse-pdt-and-custom-phpdoc-annotations)

Does anybody know a way to achieve this or a plugin for eclipse which does this? I'm using the Mars release for PHP developers.

Comment: I'm also curious about their phpdoc rendering engine. Be sure to update here anything you find out.

Comment: I will. But at the moment it seems I have to develop my own rendering engine. With blackjack and hookers! ;-)

Comment: Your university curriculum sounds more fun than mine was.